# disable logout after adding user django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-forms

I need to create admin panel in django , admin will be able to add students"which extended from users " , I finally be able to add them , but after that I get "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
User is added to the database correctly , But django logged me out !
How Can I keep my current user session !

```
 class student(models.Model):

    Computers = 1
    Communications = 2
    Dep_CHOICES = (
        (Computers, 'Computers'),
        (Communications, 'Communications'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dep = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Dep_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    deg = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for Python 2
        return self.user.username


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created):
    if created:
        student.objects.create(user=instance)


def save_user_profile(sender, instance , **kwargs):
    instance.student.save()



class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')


class studentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = student
        fields = ('dep', 'deg')
```

The view

```
def add_stu(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "add_student.html")
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = studentForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.student)

        user_form.save()
        profile_form.save()
```

Comment: why are you adding `instance=request.user` and `instance=request.user.student`, you need to understand when signing up as a new user there is no logged in user.

Comment: I tried to remove them , the user created successfully but student didn't get the input data
I get 
integrityError at /add_stu/
NOT NULL constraint failed: helwan_student.user_id

Comment: yeah that is because you are also trying to save student that has a foreign key relation to user. you need to student's user field also in order to save student form

Comment: Yeah that was the problem , Thanks for you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't save profile_form directly as it has a foreign key relation to user and is required. so before you can save profile_form you need to save user and then add the user to profile.

```
def add_stu(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "add_student.html")
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = studentForm(request.POST)
        new_user = user_form.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = new_user
        profile.save()
```

Comment: Glad to help. :)